# Mostrar fecha Date de sql en diferente formato c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla

### Tabla_User

- UserId pk int
- name nvarchar(50)
- lastlogin Date

Y al iniciar mi programa muestra un saludo en el formulario de esta manera:

```
PUBLIC PARTIAL CLASS BIENVENIDA: FORM
{
PUBLIC BIENVENIDA()
 {INITIALIZECOMPONENT();
  LABEL_NAME.TEXT = USERCACHE.NAME
  LABEL_DATE.TEXT = USERCACHE.LASTLOGIN
  }
}
 El resultado OBTENIDO es el formato largo:

**Ángel 12/12/2020 0:00:00**

Quiero transformarlo a este formato:

**Ángel 12/12/2020**

Es bastante simple pero no se como hacerlo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando quieres enlazar un control a un campo de una tabla lo que debes hacer es marcar tu control, que en este caso es un **Label** e ir al **inspector de objeto**, y seleccionar la propiedad **DataBindings** y dentro de esta seleccionar la **propiedad Text** y seleccionar ahí el **DataSource** que nos enlaza con la tabla deseada, y seleccionar dentro de ese **DataSource**, el campo que queremos mostrar en el **Label**, para dar formato, igualmente dentro de la **propiedad DataBindings** marcamos la **propiedad Advanced** y en la ventana que se nos abre, en la lista que dice **Format type**, escogemos el tipo de formato que queremos dar que en este caso es **DateTime** y vemos específicamente el formato para fecha que deseamos, cuando enlazamos un control a una fuente de datos no nos tenemos que preocupar por escribir en el control, de eso se va a encargar ya el control enlazado.

Debes aprender a usar los componentes **BindingSource** en **C#** que son los que nos permiten enlazar nuestros controles a la base de datos.

Comment: puedes darme un ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117966/japv entra aquí pa hablar por el chat

Comment: @AxlAlxanderArcaya resolviste?

Comment: No he tenido tiempo